# Displaying text alternatively on a certain time period from a database using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to jQuery. I need to display *customer testimonials* from a database on a certain time interval. Something like the one shown on this [site](http://www.subhashsarees.com/products.aspx). There is a *Testimonials* container on this site within which testimonials are displayed one by one from the database on a certain time period. I tried for a long time on Google but to no luck. If you know any links where I can download such a script, it will be very helpful to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could look at how it's done at the site you linked, right [here](http://www.subhashsarees.com/scripts/testimonials.js)

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var el = $("#testimonial");
        if (el) {
            RotateTestimonial();
            setInterval(RotateTestimonial, 20000);
        }
    });

    function RotateTestimonial() {
        var pageUrl = "RandomTestimonial.php"
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: pageUrl,
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#testimonial").slideUp('slow').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                    var el = $("#testimonial");  //Refers to some container tag like <div> or <span> where the random message is to be written.
                    el.html(msg);
                    el.slideDown('slow').fadeIn('slow');
                });
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Nice. I was about to post the exact same answer.

Comment: OP:  "I'm very new to jQuery."

Comment: OP: "If you know any links where I can download such a script".

Comment: It helped me a lot and I could achieve what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This code sets a 20 second timer to load HTML returned from YourPageHereReturnsHTML.aspx into the testimonial div.

```
<div id="testimonial">
</div>

<script>
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el = $("#testimonial");
    if (el){
    RotateTestimonial();
    setInterval(RotateTestimonial, 20000);
    }
});

function RotateTestimonial(){
    var pageUrl = "YourPageHereReturnsHTML.aspx"
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: pageUrl,
            cache:false,
            success: function(msg) {                   
                $("#testimonial").slideUp('slow').fadeOut(3000, function (){
                    var el = $("#testimonial"); 
                    el.html(msg);
                    el.slideDown('slow').fadeIn('slow');
                });
            }
    });
}
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

Comment: It helped me a lot and I could achieve what I wanted. I don't have the privilege to upvote. I will surely upvote it later, if I get that privilege. Thank you very much.